# Вращение изображения влево в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap, qtransform

Как повернуть изображение влево?

Помогите реализовать метод `left_rotate()`, который реализует мою задумку.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QPushButton, \
    QLineEdit, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform


class Rotate(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Вращение изображения')

        # Кнопка загрузки изображения
        self.btn = QPushButton('Показать картинку', self)
        self.btn.move(120, 340)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.run)

        # Кнопка переворота изображения на 90° налево
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Перевернуть изображение на 90° влево", self)
        self.btn1.move(120, 360)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.left_rotate)

        # Поле для ввода имени файла
        self.file_name = QLineEdit(self)
        self.file_name.move(140, 20)

        # Изображение
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.move(80, 60)
        self.image.resize(250, 250)
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def run(self):
        self.pixmap.load(self.file_name.text())
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def left_rotate(self):
        p = QPixmap().load(self.file_name.text())
        t = QTransform().rotate(+90)
        self.image.setPixmap(p.transformed(t))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Rotate()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication,
                             QLabel, QScrollArea, QGridLayout, QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.lbl = QLabel() 

        scroll_area = QScrollArea() 
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.lbl) 
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        open_btn = QPushButton() 
        open_btn.setText('Показать изображение')
        open_btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

#       Кнопка переворота изображения на 90° налево
        self.rotate_btn = QPushButton("Перевернуть изображение на 90° влево")
        self.rotate_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rotate_btn.clicked.connect(self.left_rotate)        

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(scroll_area, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(open_btn, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.rotate_btn, 2, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def show_image(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                      "Open Image", ".", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)")
        if fileName:
            self.pixmap = QPixmap(fileName)
            self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
            self.rotate_btn.setEnabled(True)

    def left_rotate(self):
        t = QTransform().rotate(+90)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.pixmap.transformed(t))
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(500, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]